# Calculate between two day and calculate a fine

Tags: php, date, between

```
$date2 = $row['returnbefore'];

$date1 = date('Y/m/d');

$diff = abs(strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

$final = ($days * 10) ;

echo $final;
```

i want to do a library system when user return book will check the return date between current date and calculate a fine to user which multiply day by 10 . 
what step i left ? and i wan set the current time is my computer time so i can test it

Comment: Well don't use `abs()` for a start..... because then if I return a book before it's due, I'll be fined as well

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple problem to accomplish using DateTime and DateInterval.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$dueDate = new DateTime($row['returnbefore']);

$lateInterval = $now - $dueDate;
$daysLate = $lateInterval->format('d');
$fine = $daysLate > 0 ? intval(floor($daysLate)) * 10 : 0; // This means that you are not charged for a late day until the end of the day
```